# Gitlab runner: verify vs status

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two runners: one on Linux works fine, but one on Windows has problems that I try to solve. In order to know the current state of the runner I use two commands: `verify` and `status`. When I run verify:

```
>gitlab-runner.exe verify
```

outputs:

```
Verifying runner... is alive                      ←[0;m  runner←[0;m=c6xxxxxx
```

while status

```
>gitlab-runner.exe status
```

outputs:

```
gitlab-runner: Service is not running.
```

#### Question

What is a difference between *being alive* and *running*?

#### PS

This questions is not about why it is not running, it is about understanding the status.

#### gitlab-runner version

```
Version:      10.6.0
Git revision: a3543a27
Git branch:   10-6-stable
GO version:   go1.9.4
Built:        2018-03-22T08:34:34+00:00
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*gitlab-runner. exe status* tells you, if the Service is running. It seems that you've stopped it with *gitlab-runner.exe stop*.

*gitlab-runner.exe verify* tells you if your Runner ist still registered to a GitLab Instance. If you or someone else removed it in the GitLab CI/CD settings, your Runner would'nt be alive anymore.

Comment: So alive = registered? Not very intuitive.